# How can I customize Orchard CMS to allow users to own one or more stores and stores to own products?

Tags: permissions, orchardcms

I'd like to build a "mall" using Orchard CMS with multiple "stores" with their own "products" and one or more "staff" who can manage the store and its products but where visitors can see all the products across all the stores (thus not multi-tenant). I don't need real ecommerce (no transactions, no shipping calculations, more like a craigslist)

The "big questions" seem to be:

1. Just because I've found this hammer, is this project really a nail?
2. Can permissions be managed so that each staff member can manage all the stores products, but not interfere with other stores?
3. Is building this into the admin dashboard going to end in tears?

Your guidance on techniques/modules/experiences relating to any of these would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

James

[image: Basic Entities]